# C# Access dynamic class instance field

Tags: c#

```
namespace ACPlan {

    public Class ACUnits {
    
        public List<ACUnit> ACUnits_List = new List<ACUnit>();
        
        public ACUnits() {
        
            ACUnits_List.add(...);
            ACUnits_List.add(...);
            ACUnits_List.add(...);
            ACUnits_List.add(...);
        
        }
    
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in another class:

```
Type x = Type.GetType("ACPlan.ACUnits");

dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(x);
```

`instance.ACUnits_List`  // retrieves ACUnits_List.  **GOOD!**

Now, I need to be able to specify "ACUnits_List" as a variable, BUT:

```
string field = "ACUnits_List";
```

`instance.field` // exception - instance does not contain a definition for field

`instance[field]` // Cannot apply indexing with []

`instance.GetFields()` // instance does not contain a definition for 'GetFields'

And yet, `instance.ACUnits_List` works just fine.

How do I get `ACUnits_List` when it's field name is in a variable?

**EDIT:** Also, `instance.GetType()` does return

```
{Name = "ACUnits" FullName = "ACPlan.ACUnits"}
```

So, I believe `instance` is in fact an instance of my class.

Answer (score 0):

[`.GetField()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfield?view=net-6.0) is the method from `Type`.

You need to get the field (`FieldInfo`) from `Type` first.

And to get the value from the field you need to pass the instance as below:

```cs
FieldInfo fieldInfo = x.GetField(field);
List<ACUnit> fieldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CMkfMB)